# Using Python's http.server, can I disable directory listings?

Tags: python, http, server, directory

If I run `python -m http.server` on the command line, then navigate in a browser to a directory that doesn't contain `index.html`, I see a directory listing (as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET)).

A production server in this situation, however, will generally refuse to list the contents of the directory and instead return status `403` or `404`. Can I configure `http.server` to do the same?

Comment: It looks like this should be straightforward to do in code (by subclassing `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and overriding the `list_directory` method), but I don't think it's possible from the command line. So instead, I've switched to using the Node.js-based [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) with `-d false`.